# Unit test a FeignClient using MockWebServer

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-cloud-feign, mockwebserver

I have a `FeignClient` I've developed using `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign`. I'd like to write a unit test using `MockWebServer`. How do I set up the Spring configuration for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by configuring client-side load balancing using `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer`. If you are using Gradle, add this to `build.gradle`:

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer'
```

Then you can write your test like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoClientTest {
    @Autowired
    DemoClient client;

    static MockWebServer demoServer;

    @AfterAll
    static void stopMockServer() throws IOException {
        demoServer.close();
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableFeignClients(clients = DemoClient.class)
    static class Config {
        static {
            demoServer = new MockWebServer();
            try {
                demoServer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }

        @Bean
        ServiceInstanceListSupplier serviceInstanceListSupplier() {
            return ServiceInstanceListSuppliers.from("mt-server", new DefaultServiceInstance(
                "instance1", "service1",
                demoServer.getHostName(), demoServer.getPort(),
                false
            ));
        }
    }
```

Then you can write tests like this:

```
    @Test
    void demoEndpoint_500_throws() {
        demoServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(500));
        assertThrows(FeignException.class, () -> client.demoEndpoint());
    }
```